# From async/await in C# to Closures in Swift

Tags: swift

Coming from a C# background with async/await mindset I'm having some troubles to understand how to use closures in Swift properly.

I'm using the following method `getMessagingId` to get the firebase messaging ID. After I receive the ID via a closure I want to do something with the ID. However, I simply don't know how to get that value out of `InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID(...)` so that I can use it in the methods `processMessagingId()` and `registerMessagingId()` later. In C# I would use async/await to achieve that.

```
// Register this device
public func registerThisDevice() {
    // get the messaging ID
    var messagingId = getMessagingId()

    // process this messaging ID
    processMessagingId(messagingId)

    // register this messaging ID
    registerMessagingId(messagingId)
}

// get the messaging ID for firebase messaging
func getMessagingId() -> String {
    InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID(handler: { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error fetching messaging id: \(error)")
        } else if let result = result {
            print("Messaging id is \(result.token)")
        }
    })
    return ""
}
```

`handler` is a completion handler that also uses `@escaping` keyword.

I read a couple of articles about completion handlers and also @escaping. But I just can't wrap my head around this.

Comment: You can't return your async call result synchronously

Comment: So how in swift would be the correct way to achieve this scenario? Or am I looking at it completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're doing *async* calls, you need to wait until *async* call ends and after that you can work with received data. For this we're using completion handlers in Swift.

Start with declaring completion parameter instead of having returning value

```
func getMessagingId(completion: @escaping (String) -> ())
```

What does that means?

Simplified, you declare what should happen when `completion` is called from this method. You want to pass parameter of type `String` which you can use in `completion`'s closure and then you want to call code inside `completion`'s closure

So now let's call our `completion` and as parameter let's pass our message

```
if let error = error {
    completion("Error fetching messaging id: \(error)")
} else if let result = result {
    completion("Messaging id is \(result.token)")
}
```

Ok, now let's call our method

```
getMessagingId { message in // here you give `String` parameter name
    print(message) // this code gets executed when you call `completion` in `getMessagingId`
}
```

---

Now once you're able to understand this, you can pass multiple parameters like for example `success`, `error`, `messageId`, whatever you need...

Comment: better too pass the error also to the completion handler and make String optional  `(String?, Error?) -> ()`

Comment: and then you can pass the completion handler to the instanceID call `InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID(handler: completion)`

Comment: @LeoDabus then there is no need to have `getMessagingId` method, right?

Comment: ? when calling `getMessagingId() { string, error in`

Comment: no, if he used `InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID(handler: completion)` then he doesn't have to have separate method for getting message id

Comment: kkk sure my bad

Comment: Which means that I have to nest closures in closures to achieve that goal.

Comment: @Stephan exactly

Answer (score 0):

You can use this framework for Swift coroutines - https://github.com/belozierov/SwiftCoroutine

When you call await it doesn’t block the thread but only suspends coroutine, so you can use it in the main thread as well.

```
func awaitGetMessagingId() throws -> String {
    let (result, error) = try Coroutine.await {
        InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID(handler: $0)
    }
    if let error = error { throw error }
    return result ?? ""
}
```

and then call this method inside coroutine:

```
DispatchQueue.main.startCoroutine {
    let id = try awaitGetMessagingId()
    print("Messaging id is \(id)")
}
```